# Oracle / ADO.NET - ORA: 00904 "Invalid Identifier" error when calling from C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle, ado.net

I'm trying to do a bog-standard select statement from an oracle database using ADO.NET, and getting the following:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

The ADO code looks like this:

```
conn.Open();

var command = new OracleCommand(sql) {Connection = conn};

var result = command.ExecuteReader();

//do stuff with result
```

and the sql statement is

```
select pt.*
from print_table pt
left join business_table bt on bt.transaction_id = pt.transaction_id
```

Both columns are `number(10)`. If I execute the same sql on the database directly, it's fine.

If I ditch the join:

```
select pt.*
from print_table pt
```

and run from ADO, it works.

Furthermore, if I change the sql to

```
select pt.*
from print_table pt, business_table bt
where pt.transaction_id = bt.transaction_id (+)
```

and run from ADO, it works. I'd rather not use this though (there's a lot more to the query in reality).

and, if I select named values, thus:

```
select pt.column1, pt.column2, pt.column3
from print_table pt
left join business_table bt on bt.transaction_id = pt.transaction_id
```

this, again, works fine.

Any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: I think you need to track down *exactly* what SQL statement is being sent to Oracle..

Comment: Agreed - open to tips on doing that.

Comment: To create a trace file on the server execute these statements after making your connection:     alter session set timed_statistics=true;
alter session set max_dump_file_size=unlimited;
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';
alter session set TRACEFILE_IDENTIFIER='MY_APP';

Comment: Why would you not want to use the column names in the SELECT.  It's regarded as bad practice to use SELECT *.

Comment: @RMANExpress - i'm not running select * in reality, but select * is the simplest query that replicates the error.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: It's on version 11 - sorry don't have the exact version number to hand.